# NoMethodError at /user/profile - undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass - Sinatra App using DataMapper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper, nomethoderror

Hi I am getting rotating errors with a Sinatra App. I am using DataMapper 1.1 and Ruby 1.9.2-p136. I have searched and hacked exhaustingly prior to seeking assistance here.

Things I've questioned/tried:
How is a new user being created if DataMapper #update doesn't create new record if it doesn't exist?
So I tried first_or_create which didn't solve the issue.
This is when I added the unless create.
I have been debugging this for 3 days and I am definitely open to a refactor. In fact I will for sure do a refactor however I want to get this resolved first so that I learn from the mistakes. Specifically I don't want to use the "unless" codes and I feel there's a much better way of writing the /after_login section.

I have been camping on irc #datamapper #sinatra #ruby -- although there've been generous attempts, no luck yet.

Lastly, the original code worked with DataMapper 0.9 which made me think it was a DM issue, however I think now that might not be the case.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Gists:

git://gist.github.com/897342.git
-- ruby app file -- added the unless create (I feel that this has a lot of problems)

git://gist.github.com/895532.git
-- ruby app file -- before hacked attempt to add create call

git://gist.github.com/895394.git
-- user.rb file

git://gist.github.com/895391.git
-- error backtrace

=== update:
After many hours of code wrangling and such and the great help from the irc groups #datamapper #sinatra and #ruby !! thanks to all that helped especially Dkubb!
I am semi-happy to report that I've cleared out the NoMethodErrors and am now on to some other issues, mainly knowing what exactly all of my code is doing, more faithful testing, and a general overall refactor.

I will keep updating this for those who are interested.

The general fix was to separate my methods and classes so I know what's being called, why, and how. Specifically @user was causing quite a few problems. So Sinatra error was being truthful. ;-)

Comment: In the first user.rb file, you have '@User' instead of '@user'. you fix this in the second file, where you also add the create. if you fix that typo in just the original, does it work?

Comment: Thanks for the response YenTheFirst, to answer your question I tried this and got the same error. In my attempts to debug this I actually switched that to @User which is why the two files were different.

Comment: Hi YenTheFirst, I wanted to update you, it appears I needed to reference User in both the app file and the user.rb file rather than @user or @User. There were other issues and still are, but I am hitting them one item at a time.